# Accepting a range as an array parameter

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a function that takes an array and outputs another array. Its internals are more complicated than the toy example below.

```
Public Function divide_by_2_5(ByRef coeffs() As Double) As Double()
    Dim Columns As Integer
    Columns = UBound(coeffs, 2) - LBound(coeffs, 2) + 1
    Dim output() As Double
    ReDim output(1 To 1, 1 To Columns)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Columns
        output(1, i) = coeffs(1, i) / 2.5
    Next i
    divide_by_2_5 = output
End Function
```

Here's what I see:

[image]

I would like the second row to instead contain the function's output. In this case, that would be `0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4`.

Unfortunately, I get a `#VALUE!` error and I don't know how to debug this.

Some clarification: clearly it is possible to have the same function return an array or have it write to the spreadsheet (with `Ctrl`-`Shift`-`Enter`). In an analogous fashion, is it possible for the input to come from either a range or an array?

Comment: If you want to pass a range of cells into the function, you will need to declare the passed parameter as either Range or Variant.

Comment: Your `ReDim output(1, coeffs)` statement should be `ReDim output(1, columns)`.

Comment: @YowE3K, thanks, edited

Comment: @YowE3K, can you please expand on your other comment?

Comment: But was that edit because of a typo, or was it a mistake in your code?  (If a mistake, it would generate #VALUE! errors.)

Comment: @YowE3K, it was a mistake, but I'm still getting the same behaviour

Comment: The best I can come up with is two functions, one calling the other.   (Hmmm, having said that, and posting another answer, I wonder if I could use a parameter type of `Object`???)

Comment: Have updated my second answer so that it detects whether it was passed a Range or not.  If passed a Range, it immediately converts it to an array, then continues processing.  So .... one function, able to receive a range (and be called as an array-UDF or from VBA) **or** an array (and be called from VBA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Public Function divide_by_2_5(coeffs As Variant) As Double()
    Dim v() As Variant
    If TypeName(coeffs) = "Range" Then
        v = coeffs.Value
    Else
        v = coeffs
    End If
    Dim output() As Double
    ReDim output(LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1), LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2))
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    For r = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
        For c = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
            output(r, c) = v(r, c) / 2.5
        Next
    Next
    divide_by_2_5 = output
End Function
```

An example of calling this as a UDF would be:

```
{=divide_by_2_5(C2:F2)}
```

An example of calling this from VBA using a Range might be:

```
Dim v As Variant
v = divide_by_2_5(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:F2"))
```

An example of calling this from VBA using an array might be:

```
Sub test()
   Dim x(1, 4) As Variant
   Dim v As Variant
   x(1, 1) = 6
   x(1, 2) = 7
   x(1, 3) = 8
   x(1, 4) = 9
   v = divide_by_2_5(x)
   MsgBox v(1, 3)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the passed parameter to a `Range` variable.

```
Public Function divide_by_2_5(ByRef inputRange As Range) As Double()
    Dim output() As Double
    ReDim output(1 To inputRange.Rows.Count, 1 To inputRange.Columns.Count) As Double
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    For r = 1 To inputRange.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To inputRange.Columns.Count
            output(r, c) = inputRange.Cells(r, c).Value / 2.5
        Next
    Next
    divide_by_2_5 = output
End Function
```

Note: I was originally thinking I could just have a Variant array passed into the function, but was confused because I tested using a header of

```
Public Function divide_by_2_5(ByRef x As Variant) As Double()
```

instead of

```
Public Function divide_by_2_5(ByRef x() As Variant) As Double()
```

So the version I was testing wasn't accepting a Variant **array**, just a Variant containing a Range object.  And then in my subsequent testing code, I was successfully accessing things like `x(i)`, but that wasn't returning the i-th element of the Variant array - it was just returning the i-th cell of the Range.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my code. Did you test this btw? I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I tested something similar - I may have made a mistake "translating" it back to your variables, etc.  Give me a second and I will check.

Comment: Sigh - it's the UBound causing issues - I'm going to delete my answer

Comment: Don't, explain please, the internet will learn from this, even if it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: I think I can salvage it - the Variant will be being passed a range object so I should be able to just try and change it to work on a Range and return a Range.

Comment: @user357269 - OK, I have rewritten it to use a Range variable as the parameter.  (And tested it, with the exact code posted.)  It will probably crash though if the input range and the output range are not the exact same shapes.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question is whether I can make this a function that handles both array and range inputs. You mentioned using `Variant`?

Comment: How do you intend to create the array that you want to pass to the function?

Comment: That's the thing, I would like it to work for both ranges and arrays created in VBA (updated my quesiton)

Answer (score 0):

if you would like D2, E2, F2, G2 to be equal to 0.4, you need to pass on one singe value to your function, like:

```
Public Function divide_by_2_5 (ByRef coeff As Range) As Double
         divide_by_2_5 = coeff.Value / 2.5
End Function
```

make the following call: `=divide_by_2_5(D1)` on D2 and then drag it until G2.

I think a UDF can only add a value to its calling cell only

Comment: I originally thought a UDF could only act on a single cell too, but it can actually output to multiple cells if it is entered as an array formula.

Comment: I've learnt more just from trying to answer SO questions than I have in years and years of using Excel.