# Stopping an 1 by n array from being converted to a 1-dimensional one

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Below is some code I wrote to handle arrays and ranges uniformly ([Accepting a range as an array parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439890/accepting-a-range-as-an-array-parameter)). It contains a function called `sanitise` which is meant to be a function you can call on some 2D collection of numbers `A`, and get the same numbers back as a 2D array of Doubles.

```
Public Function item(ByRef A As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer) As Double
    If TypeName(A) = "Range" Then
        item = A.Cells(i, j)
    Else
        item = A(i, j)
    End If
End Function

Public Function rows(ByRef A As Variant) As Integer
    If TypeName(A) = "Range" Then
        rows = A.rows.Count
    Else
        rows = UBound(A, 1) - LBound(A, 1) + 1
    End If
End Function

Public Function cols(ByRef A As Variant) As Integer
    If TypeName(A) = "Range" Then
        cols = A.columns.Count
    Else
        cols = UBound(A, 2) - LBound(A, 2) + 1
    End If
End Function

Public Function sanitise(ByRef A As Variant) As Double()

    Debug.Print TypeName(A)

    If TypeName(A) = "Double()" Then
        sanitise = A
    Else
        Debug.Print rows(A)

        Dim B() As Double
        ReDim B(1 To rows(A), 1 To cols(A))

        Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
        For i = 1 To rows(A)
            For j = 1 To cols(A)
                B(i, j) = item(A, i, j)
            Next j
        Next i

        sanitise = B
    End If
End Function
```

The implementation works exactly as you'd expect it: select a range in the worksheet, say `A1:B2`, call sanitize on it and you'll have two copies of the same thing:

[image]

What goes wrong however, is `sanitise`^2.

Calling `sanitise` twice breaks down, but **only if you call it on single row**. Multiple rows: fine, single column: fine.

[image]

I know why it happens: after the first `sanitise`, Excel forgets what shape array was returned. (It also forgets the type: instead of `Double()` the input to the second `sanitise` is `Variant()`)

Does anybody know how to work around this issue?

While it's unlikely that I'd ever want to use `sanitise` twice in a row, the above example illustrates why it's difficult to compose two functions along a 2 dimensional array.

Note: this is issue only happens when `sanitise` is called from a worksheet.

**Update, I've figured it out**: for the worksheets 1D storage in synonymous with row, so that needs to be taken into consideration

My final version:

```
Public Function get_2D(ByRef A As Variant) As Double()
    'turns various forms of input into a 2D array of Doubles
    Dim result() As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    If TypeOf A Is Range Or dims(A) = 2 Then
        ReDim result(1 To rows(A), 1 To cols(A))
        Dim j As Integer
        For i = 1 To rows(A)
            For j = 1 To cols(A)
                result(i, j) = item(A, i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
    Else
        '1D storage is treated as a row
        ReDim result(1 To 1, 1 To rows(A)) 'rows(A) gets length of the first axis
        For i = 1 To rows(A)
            result(1, i) = A(i)
        Next i
    End If

    sanitise = result
End Function
```

`dims` is a function that returns the number of dimensions of an array: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152288

Comment: If you include a `Debug.Print cols(A)` after your `Debug.Print rows(A)` you will see that it never prints anything when the outer `sanitise` is performed, i.e. it crashes while calling `cols(A)`.  That is because the inner `sanitise` has returned a (1 To 1, 1 To 2) shaped array, which has been converted (no idea why - Excel is weird sometimes) to a (1 To 2) shaped array prior to being passed into the outer `sanitise` and your code doesn't handle a one-dimensional array, just a range or a two-dimensional array.

Comment: I could not replicate your error.  Can you provide a download link?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is somewhat aligned with your specification and it has the benefit of solving the single row problem you demonstrate. Would it work for your purposes?

```
Function sanitise_sugg(inp As Variant) As Variant
Dim result As Variant
If TypeOf inp Is Object  Then
result = inp.Value
Else
result = inp
End If
sanitise_sugg = result
End Function
```

Edit: Taking one step back I think you should divide the task at hand into two: First use "sanitise_sugg" to use excel ranges and excel-vba arrays interchangeabely. Then if you for a special need demand the input to specifcally be some sort of Array of doubles, write a separate function that tests and if possible casts a variant input to this type.

Edit 2: Taking one step forward instead, let me claim that in the case the elements fed to `Function sanitise_sugg(inp As Variant) As Variant` contain doubles from within vba, or cells with numeric values from an excel sheet, it meets the specifciation demanded for `Public Function sanitise(ByRef A As Variant) As Double()`

Edit 3: To see how the function keeps track of its input Array layout independently of beeing Row vector, Column vector or full Matrix, independently of beeing passed the Array from an excel range or from within VBA, please refer to the below worksheet;

[image]

Comment: Very cool! The goal of `sanitise` is that whatever your input is, you always know that the output is 2D `Double` array. That way you know how to access elements: it's `B(1, i)` if you pass in a row.

Comment: I think that specification is reaching too far. What if your inputs are e.g. text strings? With "sanitise_sugg" you have at least met the specification of knowing how to access the elements regardless of whether those are rows, columns or matrices.

Comment: Thanks Mats, your answer really helped me figure out what was wrong! See the bottom of my question for an update to see what I ended up going with.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any practical use for this unless you do a lot of calculations on the 2D array of Doubles, so if you give more information on what exactly you are trying to do, we can probably recommend something easier/better/more efficient etc.

`.Value` and `.Value2` return 2D Variant array when more than one cell in the range:

```
v = [a1:b1].Value2  ' Variant/Variant(1 to 1, 1 to 2)
v = [a1:a2].Value2  ' Variant/Variant(1 to 2, 1 to 1)
v = [a1].Value2     ' Variant/Double
```

so a naive approach can be something like:

```
Function to2D(v) As Double()
    'Debug.Print TypeName(v), VarType(v)
    Dim d2() As Double, r As Long, c As Long
    If IsArray(v) Then
        If TypeOf v Is Range Then v = v.Value2
        ReDim d2(1 To UBound(v, 1), 1 To UBound(v, 2))
        For r = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
            For c = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
                If IsNumeric(v(r, c)) Then d2(r, c) = v(r, c)
            Next c
        Next r
    Else
        ReDim d2(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        If IsNumeric(v) Then d2(1, 1) = v
    End If
    to2D = d2
End Function
```

and tested with:

```
d2 = to2D([a1:b2])
d2 = to2D([a1:b1])
d2 = to2D([a1:a2])
d2 = to2D([a1])
d2 = to2D(1)
d2 = to2D([{" 1 ";" 2.0 "}]) ' works with strings too
d2 = to2D([{1,2;3,4}]) 
'd2 = to2D([{1,2}]) ' doesn't work with 1D arrays
```

Comment: This is cool, but it doesn't square! Try out `{=to2D(to2D(A1:B1))}`

Comment: I'm using VBA for data analysis on financial data, so it's all doubles and arrays thereof